# Replacing lower capacity disk for Drobo on Linux

Tags: linux, drobo

Connecting Drobo Gen2 (4-slots) to a Red Hat Linux 6.2 box.  Using drobo-util-0.6.2.2.
Old disks are 1x 3TB, 2x 1TB, 1x 750GB.  New disks inserted are 3x 3TB disks and 1x 1TB disk.

When I run 'drobom info', it shows -

```
Capacity (in GB): used 2375, free: 6591, total:8966
```

However 'df' shows only 5.5TB.  This is the capacity before I replace the disks.

```
Filesystem          Size   Used   Avail   Use%  Mounted on
/dev/mapper/xx-1    5.5T   5.3T   167GB   98%   /sata
```

Do I have to manually format the new disks/run some drobom commands to make the new disk space available?

Thanks.

Comment: Were you just striping all these disks into a giant RAID 0 volume? Because that's what it looks like, and that's a *really* bad idea. If one single drive fails, the entire array will be utterly hosed.

Comment: No it should not be RAID 0.  I never use drobom before so I'm not sure how to confirm it.  However when i pulled out a disk, I can still continue to access my data.